# Class method that accesses the array the class instance is inside

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Using python 2.7- I have a file, `main.py`, that does something like

```
from tile import Tile
l = [Tile(), Tile(), Tile()]
```

where `tile.py` contains the Tile class. I need the Tile class to access `l` in the main file. For example, I could:

- Write a method in Tile that returns the instance of Tile before it in the list.
- I could write a method from within Tile that returns all the other Tile instances in the list it's in.

These would work no matter what list the class instance was in. Is this possible to do in python?

## EDIT

---

*Exactly* what I'm trying to do: I have a `Tile` class. `world` is a 2D array, a list of lists. The lists have `Tile` class objects. I'm trying to implement a method of `Tile`, `returnNeighbors()`, that returns the tiles to the top, bottom, left and right in the array.

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your design. Usually, when you have to do weird things to access data, it's a design flaw.

Comment: You would be better off making the list an attribute of the class.

Comment: @BrenBarn- This won't work if I need to have many lists with Tile objects in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can access the list from inside the class unless you pass it as a function. You could try that, but as others have mentioned, this generally means that the design is bad and you should rethink it.

```
<inside the class Tile>
# function for the first use-case in your question
def your_function(self, your_list):
    return your_list[your_list.index(self) -1]

# second use-case
def your_other_function(self, your_list):
    temp = your_list
    temp.remove(self)
    return temp
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll do this.